# Como traer información de distintas tablas

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, datos

Necesito traer información de varias tablas usando INNER JOIN con MySQL.
La situación es la siguiente:
Tengo una consulta que me trae un reporte de las ventas por departamento que se hicieron en un determinado rango de fechas, la consulta solo muestra los departamentos en los cuales se hizo la venta y la cantidad correspondiente, pero necesito que me muestre TODOS los departamentos aunque en estos no haya ventas, se pueden mostrar en 0.
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
 SELECT 
 CAST(vd.gcs_FechaCreacion AS DATE) AS gcs_Fecha, 
 vd.gcs_DepartamentoItem gcs_Departamento, vd.gcs_DepartamentoCodeItem AS gcs_CodigoDepto, 
 SUM(vd.gcs_TotalGlobal - (vd.gcs_TotalGlobal * ven.gcs_PDescuento / 100) ) 
 AS gcs_Importe FROM gcs_01ventasdetalle vd INNER JOIN gcs_01ventas ven 
 on vd.gcs_Code = ven.gcs_Code INNER JOIN ocrd proveedores 
 ON ven.gcs_CodigoCliente = proveedores.CardCode 
 WHERE vd.gcs_Estatus > - 1 AND TRIM(ven.gcs_Estatus) 
 NOT IN ('C','CS') AND vd.gcs_FechaCreacion 
 BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT('01/10/2020', ' 00:00:00'), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')
 AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT( '01/01/2022', '23:59:59'), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') 
 AND proveedores.GroupCode = '100' 
 AND TRIM(ven.gcs_VCredito) = 'N' 
 GROUP BY CAST(vd.gcs_FechaCreacion AS DATE) , vd.gcs_DepartamentoItem ;
```

Observaciones:
En otra tabla aparte, tengo almacenados los departamentos por codigo y nombre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes intentar es usar simplemente la clausula `JOIN` en vez de usar `INNER JOIN`.

Una manera de obtener todo la combinación con respecto a los conjuntos de datos (tablas) es usar la clausula `FULL JOIN`